# Building a Windows Forms application and trying to receive an access token from Paypal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, paypal

I am building a Windows Forms application with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.

I am trying to receive an access token from paypal using c# HTTP POST request. I keep getting the following message:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Am I missing something in my code?

Thanks alot!

This is my code:

```
        string ClientID = "1234";
        string secret = "****";

        WebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create(" https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";           
        string PostData = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(String.Format("Accept=application/json&Accept-Language=en_US&user-id={0}&password={1}&grant_type=client_credentials", ClientID, secret));
        byte[] ByteArray =Encoding.Default.GetBytes(PostData);
        Request.ContentLength = ByteArray.Length;
        Request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + ByteArray;
        Stream dataStream;

        using ( dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(ByteArray, 0, ByteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }

        WebResponse respones = Request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)respones).StatusDescription);
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)respones).Server);
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)respones).ResponseUri);

        dataStream = respones.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string ResponesFromServer = sReader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(ResponesFromServer);

        dataStream.Close();
        sReader.Close();
        respones.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its show authentication problem. Try to use http basic authentication.

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ClientID:secret");
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + base64;
```

See this [Link for more help](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#authentication--headers)

They give some curl example. It guides u generate Access token.